# Jquery export csv Safari on Mac issue Mime Types & IE9 export issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, csv, safari, mime-types

I am exporting my html table to csv which works fine in Chrome and Firefox, and in safari on Windows it works ok - you get the option to open or save file albeit withthe name Unknown but if you do this and open downloads the file is there and opens correctly.

However, on Safari on a Mac it will try to open it in another browser window and fail.

There are a couple of options that I am looking into:

1. Create a seperate button to export CSV for Safari MAc
2. make the browser open a 'Open/Save As' dialog box.
3. Other suggestion on  best way to do this..?

I've had a look around and i think the answer to the second point is no - you can t force a browsers behaviour.

However I haven t been able to find a way to export in safari mac or a good solution on how to do this.

The Jquery code I am using to export the csv is as follows:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

                var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

                    // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
                    // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
                    tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
                    tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

                    // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
                    colDelim = '","',
                    rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

                    // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
                    csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                        var $row = $(row),                            
                            $cols = $row.find('td');

                        return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                            var $col = $(col),
                                text = $col.text();

                            return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

                        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

                    }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                        .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                        .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

                    // Data URI
                    csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

                $(this)
                    .attr({
                        'download': filename,
                        'href': csvData,
                        'target': '_blank'
                    });
            }

            // This must be a hyperlink
            $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
                // CSV
                exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#tableContainer>table'), 'export.csv']);

                // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
                // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink

            });
        });
    </script>
```

My html table is created from ajax here is an example:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: theUrl,
        data: { 'manufacturer': manufacturer, 'country': country, 'startDate': startDate, 'endDate': endDate, 'chartType': chartType },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 50);

            if (data.length == 0) {
                $('#noData').show();
                $('#chartContainer').hide();
                $('#tableContainer').hide();
                $('#exportData').hide();
            }
            var retailerNameArray = [];
            var impressionsArray = [];
            var intsArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var impRow = data[i];


                //only display on graph if not 0
                if (impRow.RetailerImpressionCount > 0) {
                    //put into an array
                    var retailer = impRow.RetailerDescription;
                    var imps = impRow.RetailerImpressionCount;
                    retailerNameArray.push(retailer);
                    impressionsArray.push(imps);
                    var clicks = impRow.RetailerClickCount;
                    intsArray.push(clicks);

                    $('#noData').hide();
                    $('#chartContainer').show();
                    $('#tableContainer').show();
                    $('#exportData').show();

                }
            }

 var table = document.getElementById("usertable");
            var tabledata = "";
            tabledata += "<tr class =\"tableHeader\">";
            tabledata += "<td>Retailer</td>";
            tabledata += "<td>Impressions</td>";
            tabledata += "<td>Clicks</td>";
            tabledata += "<td>CTR</td>";
            tabledata += "<td>Percentage</td>";
            tabledata += "</tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var impDataRow = data[i];
                tabledata += "<tr>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.RetailerDescription + "</td>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.RetailerImpressionCount + "</td>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.RetailerClickCount + "</td>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.ClickThroughRate.toFixed(2) + "%</td>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.Percentage.toFixed(2) + "%</td>";
                tabledata += "</tr>";

            }
                //tabledata += "<tfoot>";
                tabledata += "<tr>";
                tabledata += "<td>Total</td>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.TotalImpressionCount + "</td>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.TotalClickCount + "</td>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.TotalClickThroughRate.toFixed(2) + "%</td>";
                tabledata += "<td>" + impDataRow.TotalPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%</td>";
                tabledata += "</tr>";
                // tabledata += "</tfoot>";

            table.innerHTML = tabledata;
            $("th");
            $("tr:even");
            $("tr:odd");
        }
    }
       );
    });


    //]]>
```

**Edit**

I think (though not sure) that it is this line which is not working properley in safari mac:

```
csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
```

I'm investigating this further but should this be set to something in particular for safari? - i know safari has safe mime types but do they have a safe mime type for csv ?

**Edit**

Although no ideal i have created a new button just for safari and used:

```
 csvData = 'data:text/plain,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
```

as this is recognised as a safe mime type in safari it opens it in a new tab - sort of what i was lokoing for...

Now i'm fightng with IE9 to try to find a solution which work in ie aswel.

Here are a coupe of things i ve tried so far:

http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/savedownload-file-using-html5-javascript-the-download-attribute-2/

But i can t get this to work

and

http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php

option 3.1 on this page works, but i m not familiar with php so not sure how to make it work for me.

**Edit**

Hoping this may hold the answer:

http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-creating-csv-file.html

**Edit**
now looking at this:

[Export html table to excel in asp.net MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038811/export-html-table-to-excel-in-asp-net-mvc2)

to try to get it to work..

**Edit**

Using the above works in safari and IE 10

As always any input much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what script/url your ajax is sending information to, but in PHP you should be able to force a download by using the correct content-disposition headers. I'm not sure how that would work with Ajax though.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb in the export script there is this -  // Data URI
                    csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv); is this what you mena?

Comment: I can't quite figure what you've done there and how it triggers a download. I'm not saying it's wrong, I just don't understand it. What I've done in the past is to send a form to a PHP script that has headers set like this 

    header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename=".$set."_".$start_date."_to_".$end_date.".csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

Which rather than causing a page change returns a download save dialogue.

Comment: Sorry the formatting fell off in the comment box.

Comment: @anna I'm having the exact same problem, did you ever figure out how to get this to work in IE9 or 11?

Answer (score 0):

For IE 9 this works fine, please try:

The problem happens on IE if you have, in Advanced tab on settings, "Do not save encrypted files to disk" set, and your site is running in HTTPS. This setting actively prevents downloads (of course). Doh!

Finded here: https://drupal.org/node/1736296

as for IE 5 - 8 see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308